# Google Auth with callback on server-side, that I would like to respond to in client-side

Tags: ios, swift, server, vapor

I am building an app with a **Vapor** backend, and **Imperial** for OAuth.
I am trying to implement Google and Facebook sign-in.

When I hit this endpoint: **localhost:8080/google** , the server authenticates the user, and after that, a callback executes and I receive a token and redirect to a certain path. (callback executing on server-side)

On the client side, I embed this endpoint in a WKWebview, which works fine, but the problem is, that the auth callback is happening on the server side, and not on the client side, which creates an issue, that I cannot execute client-side operations(receiving the token and doing something with it, closing webview and showing an activity indicator and so on..) after the user signed in the embedded web view.

Is there a way to make a client request somehow, to happen only inside the server-side callback after the auth completes?
Or should I approach it differently? maybe some server-push to the client, without the client requesting it?

**Backend code for the auth:**

```
 try group.oAuth(
        from: Google.self,
        authenticate: "google",
        authenticateCallback: nil,
        callback: "http://localhost:8080/google-complete",
        scope: ["profile", "email"],
        completion: processGoogleLogin
    )
```

processGoogleLogin:

```
 func processGoogleLogin(request: Request, token: String) throws -> EventLoopFuture<ResponseEncodable> {
    print("Google Token: ",token)
    return request.eventLoop.future(request.redirect(to: "/"))
    //here theoretically I want to do certain operations on the client side.
}
```

**Client-side code for embedding the webview and hitting the desired endpoint:**

```
 @objc private func googleLogin() {
    let newVC = UIViewController()

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: newVC.view.frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
    let userAgentValue = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4"
    webView.customUserAgent = userAgentValue
    
    let myURL = URL(string:"http://localhost:8080/google")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)

    webView.uiDelegate = self
    newVC.view = webView
    webView.load(myRequest)
    self.present(newVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: It definitely should work like: user opens webview with Google/Facebook oauth login which in the end redirects to your server where server could return session to the user and webview detects last endpoint, grabs session and shows success notice to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely should not be using WKWebView for authenticating users with your server, especially over OAuth. Use [`ASWebAuthenticationSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession). Then in your Vapor app in `processGoogleLogin` redirect to a scheme your iOS app knows about and pass the token as a URL query parameter. Then in the callback you can do whatever you need to on the client side.